# There exists a function that satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f^{[n]}(x) - f^{[n]}(y)| < \infty$ but is not a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

There exists a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f^{[n]}(x) - f^{[n]}(y)| < \infty \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}
$$
where $f^{[n]}(x) = f(f(f...(f(x)))$ iterated $n$ times, but there is no $\lambda < 1$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \lambda |x - y|$.
I think that a function that is not a contraction but $f(f(x))$ is, satisties my problem, but how to prove it? And how I find such function?

OBS: I prove that a function that satisfies this property has a unique fixed point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, 
f(x)=\begin{cases} 2^x \pi,& x\in \mathbb{N}, \\ 
1,& x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}. \end{cases} 
\end{align*}
We have that $f(f(x))=1$, thus, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \vert f^{[n]}(x)-f^{[n]}(y) \vert = \vert f(x)-f(y) \vert <\infty.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, we have for $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$ \vert f(n)-f(0) \vert = (2^n-2^0) \pi. $$
Assume that there exists $\lambda>0$ such that $\vert f(x)-f(y) \vert \leq \lambda \vert x-y \vert$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ yields for $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$ \lambda n \geq \vert f(n)-f(0) \vert = (2^n-2^0) \pi $$
and hence
$$ \lambda \geq \frac{2^n-1}{n}. $$
However, the RHS tends to infinity for $n\rightarrow \infty$, which yields a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

let

$$
f(x) =\begin{cases} 2x + 1 & 0 \le x < 1 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
That's not a contraction (consider $x = 0, 0.5$ being sent to $1, 2$), but $f^{[2]}$ is everywhere $0$, so it certainly has the required summation property.